# Puppeteer black screenshot

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

When I make a screenshot with the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` parameters, puppeteer returns a black screenshot, without it all works fine.
This is my code:

```js
await page.screenshot({ path: 'build.png', clip: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 810, height: 415 } });
```

Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your snippet works as expected (Windows 10, puppeteer 3.1.0). It may be an environment or webpage dependent issue (E.g. [docs say](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.3.0&show=api-pagescreenshotoptions) for OSX screenshots take at least 1/6 second).

**As a workaround you can use `page.setViewport` to crop the desired size, then do a normal screenshot.**

The images `build.png` and `build2.png` are 100% identical to me (size, crop, everything) so if the only problem for you is `clip` then you can go on with this solution.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function fn() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.setViewport({ width: 810, height: 415 })
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com')
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'build.png', clip: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 810, height: 415 } }) // your original try
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'build2.png' }) // workaround, combined with setViewport

  await browser.close()
}
fn()
```